# Couldn't transfer the datas in the row which I click on

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I've a list and I want to show the picture and the name, which I choose from my list, on another page. When I click on an item It goes to the second page but gives no picture or name. There is nothing on the page. How can solve it? What did I do wrong?

In my main activity class :

```
theList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Person x = persons.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(cnt, page2.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", x.getName());
            intent.putExtra("gender", x.isWomen());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And my second page class:

```
public class page2 extends Activity {
private ImageView imView;
private TextView tView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page2lay);

    imView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.page2Image);
    tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.page2Text);

    Rum();
}

private void Rum(){

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    boolean gender = i.getBooleanExtra("gender",false);    }
}
```

Comment: persons is your arraylist right?

Comment: yes persons is my list

Comment: are you getting data from persons list? before sending data please debug

Comment: Where is the code that you set the name and picture in the second page? And where do you pass the picture to the second page?

Comment: I am not surprised that nothing happens in the second `Activity` since you never assign any value to the `Views` there.

Comment: "setImageRecource" gets integer values and the "gender"s type is boolean. How can I assign the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kapeller said in the comments;

You should assign the name and gender to the views you called in the onCreate.

As for the TextView, just call the .settext("name") and I assume you want a gender image to be shown instead of the boolean, then you'll have to use an if(gender) statement before filling up the ImageView with .setImageBitmap() if you use Bitmaps or .setImageDrawable() if you use Drawables.

Comment: Yes I work it out. But not with Bitmap I just do it like that.                if(gender == true) {
            imView.setImageResource(R.drawable.woman);
        }
        else {
            imView.setImageResource(R.drawable.man);
        }